# How to call rest api in background even when the app is closed in ionic for android platform?

Tags: ionic-framework, background-process

We used the plugins from ionicframework documentation mentioned in the developers section for **background mode** services. but after subscribing the **background task** in ionic the code or task is executed when the app is **active or open**. The **service stops** when the app is **closed**. Need sample code help or sample source code for the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show some of your code.